# trying to extract info from a column using literal_eval

Tags: python, pandas

here is a question I encountered when I trying to extract info from a column of a dataset

the column example:

| genres |
| --- |
| [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}] |
| [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}] |

I am trying to only extract all the genre names from each column

what i tried:

`df['genres'] = df['genres'].fillna('[]').apply(literal_eval).apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else None)`

howerver this code gives me this error: `malformed node or string`, I am not sure what I did wrong.

if someone could help me fix that problem I would be really appriciate it. or if y'all have any better ways to extract,I also very welcome.

Comment: What was the input row that gave you this error?

Comment: These rows do not cause this error.  The error must be caused by other rows in the dataframe.  We can't help if you don't show the actual data that causes the problem.

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis -- Thank you, but it didn't work. it saids 'invalid syntax'

Comment: @JohnGordon -- sure, full dataset link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NQFs-wO3Rzsm5GkfApYBOXGv3r5cFyM_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @william_Li oops, there was a syntax typo: `df['genres'] = df['genres'].fillna('[]').applymap(lambda x: '[]' if not x else x).applymap(str)`

Comment: The problem may just be that you're calling `apply(literal_eval)` on the very first row, which contains the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def extract_all_genre_names(x):
    try:
        result = [d['name'] for d in eval(x)]
    except:
        result = x
    return result


out = df['genres'].apply(extract_all_genre_names)
print(out)
```